# How to play/open video file embedded with a PDF?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I have created a PDF viewer on iphone. Currently my app is able to detect **links to web pages** and **buttons for navigation within PDF**.
But it **unable to play Audio/Video contents embedded with PDF**.

I creates custom PDf which has button(link to a local video file) to play video file. But iphone can't play the video. (when I tap on button, it says "NULL file ....")

I want to know is it possible to do? and if anyone have done it please give me a help. It will be a huge help for me.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible to play a video inside a PDF,

if you cannot play the video on an iPhone, i would suggest to convert it to a file that the iPhone can play

Comment: Thanks a lot, I mean I just want to open the video when tap on the button (not to play within the PDF). I have tried with .mov and .mp4 formats, but didn't success

Comment: are you using a generator to create the pdf?

Comment: hmm i dont know much about referencing media on the iPhone sorry

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using [`PSPDFKit`](http://pspdfkit.com/).

See [`documentation`](http://pspdfkit.com/documentation.html). Its best. :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to play the pdf embedef video not by acobat official app but thru thr drop box app! Wonder why acrobat not providing the function.

https://www.dropbox.com/l/scl/AAAHBU-oAQ0GjIWW4UMzIpTNYwitnWMMfFo

This is the dropbox pdf file with embeded MP4.